# Why can I power a 9 volt application on the Collector side of a transistor, and not the Emitter if Base gets 5 volts.

Tags: voltage, transformer, voltage-divider

I have a 9 volt application that I want to trigger using an Arduino and an NPN transistor. The Arduino can supply 5 volts to the base.  I tried to place the application on the Emitter side of the transistor, and nothing happened.  I tested the circuit and found that only 5 volts were being supplied by the Emitter.  Later, I was told that if I moved the application to the Collector side, the circuit would work (and it did.)  I an confused by this.  How and why can there be two different voltages present on either side of the transistor?  Does it function as a voltage divider?  How is the voltage reduced?

Answer (score 1):

For a BJT to remain in forward active or saturated operating mode, the base-emitter junction must be forward biased. That means the emitter will be roughly 0.7 V below the base. So if you apply 5 V to the base, you'll get no more than about 4.3 V at the emitter (maybe 4.4 or 4.5 if the load takes less than a milliamp of current).

Comment: Then why and how could there be a different voltage on the Collector?  This is a huge mystery to me.

Comment: For low-side switching applications, you'll want the BJT in saturated operation. That means the collector voltage will be about 0.2 or 0.3 V above the emitter. Giving about 4.8 V to the load if its other end is tied to +5 V.

Comment: "low side" switching means the load is connected between the power supply and the bjt collector. If you aren't interested in it, why did you ask follow-up questions about it?

Comment: The answer to "why" connecting the load at the emitter doesn't work is in my answer. If the emitter voltage rises above ~4.3 V, then the BJT will shut off and not deliver any current to the load.

Comment: oops, sorry, I had my sides confused.  Why does is work on the Collector side?  Doesn't the drop in voltage between the Emitter and the Collector effect the application?  In my mind, the entire circuit should be limited to 5 volts unless there is another path to ground (like in a voltage divider.)

Comment: I must sound condescending.  I am simply trying to understand how and why my circuit works, and I am getting frustrated.

Comment: Low side switching works better because "the collector voltage will be about 0.2 or 0.3 V above the emitter. Giving about 4.8 V to the load if its other end is tied to +5 V." (what I said in my previous comment) (and it will be 8.8 V or so if the other side of the load is supplied with 9 V)